# How to prove Siegel upper half plane is a hermitian symmetric space

Tags: modular-forms, symmetric-spaces, siegel-modular-forms

There is a statement that is Siegel upper half plane of genus g, $\mathbb{H}_g:=\left\{Z=X+i Y \in M_n(\mathbb{C}) \mid X, Y \text { real }, Z=Z^{T}, Y=\operatorname{Im} Z>0\right)$ is isomorphic to hermitian symmetric space $Sp(2g,\mathbb{R})/U(g)$. So how to prove this statement? How to construct a map from $Sp(2g,\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{H}_g$ in the form of mapping a $2g*2g$ real matrix to a $g*g$ complex matrix, at least for g=2 case?

Comment: Would David E Speyer's answer in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78255/finding-the-action-of-the-symplectic-group-on-the-siegel-half-plane) help?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly look at the action of $Sp(2g,\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{H}_g$. As suggested in David E Speyer's answer, the action is given by $M \cdot Z = (AZ + B)(CZ + D)^{-1}$ . Then fix an element in $\mathbb{H}_g$, say $iI_g$, one can verify that the stabilizer is the unitary group. The quotient map is automatically given by $M\mapsto M \cdot iI_g$.